# Adding a functioning color property to my custom ionic component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create my own custom component in Ionic which allows me to set the color property of the text within it. I have been trying to use the functionality provided in ionic core to be able to add a color property. Upon a search of the source code it prompted me to try and use `createColorClasses` function, however it appears this isn't function isn't exposed. I'm wondering if there is an alternative method without, which doesn't involve writing large amounts of code.

Comment: You could change the application color based on https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/colors and them import those properties for you component and reuse then there.

Comment: Will this work if I planned on doing:

`<my-custom-component color="primary">My text</my-custom-component>`

It feels like I should need something more than updating the colours in the my theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})

export class ParentComponent {
  label: string = "Click me"
  color: string = "blue" // Or could be a hex color as string
  constructor() {}

  functioncall(event) {
    console.log('functioncall', event);
  }
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-button [color]="color" (onClick)="functioncall($event)" [label]="label"></app-button>
```

**app-buton.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  templateUrl: './button.component.html'
})

export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {}

  onClickButton(event) {
    this.onClick.emit(event);
  }
}
```

**app-buton.component.html**

```
<div id="button">
  <button [ngStyle]="{'color': color}" type="button" (click)="onClickButton($event)">
    {{ label }} {{color}}
  </button>
</div>
```

This is just an example but you can use the app-button component and pass more parameters of colors or whatever for the style and class, for more information see this: https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/